# how can we generate tuples from data Frames columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    top1    top2    top3
0   0       13      20
1   1       14      23
2   2       11      25
3   3       13      20
4   4       10      21
5   5       19      13
```

I want to generate to generate tuples like that: `[("0", "13"), ("0", "20"), ("1", "14), ("2", "11"), ("2", "25"), ....].`

How can we do that if possible? And if I want to do the same for a some given rows (not all the rows)?

Comment: What you want is to iterate the row and make two tuples from each row right?

Comment: @Nephanth yes but always the combination is between the the first element of the row with each of the other columns

Comment: Then do just that I suppose? Here is how to iterate through the rows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: But remember that this way of handling the data isn't well suited to pandas. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to generate tuple which represent edge in a graph

Comment: Would it be ok to generate a dataframe (with two columns) instead of a list of tuples? That would be way more suited to pandas

Comment: You can do what do you want just I need the tuples to be like  I want in order to generate my graph

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is pandas we are talking about

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"top1": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ... and so on})

tuples = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tuples.append((row["top1"], row["top2"]))
    tuples.append((row["top1"], row["top3"]))

print(tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to iterating over the DataFrame would be to create two columns using `zip` and then convert them to two lists and join them. `zip` is a very efficient function for this.

```
df['col1'] = list(zip(df.top1, df.top2))
df['col2'] = list(zip(df.top1, df.top3))

final_list = df.col1.to_list() + df.col2.to_list()
```

If you want to get a list of row-wise tuples, you can do this:

```
def get_edge(idx):
    lst = []
    lst.append(df.col1[idx])
    lst.append(df.col2[idx])
    return lst
```

This returns a list of the pair of tuples whose `index` you pass to the function.

Comment: Can you please update your answer in case we need to select a given row in the dataframe

Comment: Sure, you can do that by specifying the index. I've updated my answer and created a function to get a row-wise list of tuples,

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of one-line solutions:

```
pd.concat([df[['top1', 'top2']].apply(tuple, axis=1),
           df[['top1', 'top3']].apply(tuple, axis=1)]).to_list()
```

```
(df[['top1', 'top2']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
                     .append(df[['top1', 'top3']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
                     .to_list())
```